# Eclipse: how to automatically compile sources in a Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse Neon with Tomcat server. I have the following project structure:

[image]

I can't find a way to compile the DBAccess.java source file in the src folder into a .class file so that I can reference it in the index page (index.jsp). I've tried everything but all I can do is compile the index.jsp page and view it in the browser, and it works correctly unless I try to reference the DBAccess class because obviously it didn't even get compiled.

Do I actually have to compile the Java source code in the src folder separately and then manually place the .class files into the classes folder? Or am I missing/misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after a lot more research I finally found out what was happening.

My DBAccess.java file in the src folder was in the "default package" (because I ignored the warnings that it was a bad idea), so it was not possible to import the class in the index.jsp file. Once I moved the java source file into an appropriate package I was able to use the import directive to reference the class normally inside the JSP:

[image]

Apparently in my case the corresponding .class file is being generated or moved inside the `wtpwebapps/MySQLTestApp/WEB-INF/classes` folder that Eclipse created in my Tomcat environment because that's where I found it.

[image]